# PoE vs. Power over Ethernet

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I noticed there are both [poe](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/poe) and [power-over-ethernet](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/power-over-ethernet) tags. They should be merged or linked, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done. I have merged [poe](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/poe) to [power-over-ethernet](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/power-over-ethernet)

Answer (score 2):

Merge into [power-over-ethernet](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/power-over-ethernet), in my opinion.